# Extracting from a variable in puppeteer, Double extraction

Tags: puppeteer

i have huge html, i have stored a part of html to a variable. i am trying to click on a specific div in the Variable. `var nop = [...document.querySelectorAll('div .field-evaluation-component')].find(el => el.textContent === 'Supervisor ReviewYesNo');` nop variable contains html in it how to click on a div element inside nop variable in pupetter

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `div` inside `nop.children` and then call `click()` over that element. Just for example you can use something similar:

```js
const nop = [/***/].find(/***/);

if (!nop) {
  // do smth if you don't find the nop element
}

// if the nop element is founded 
// iterate over all children and call click for each div tag
// ps: update the condition for your needs 
for (let i = 0; i < nop.children.length; i++) {
  if (foo.children[i].tagName === 'DIV') {
    foo.children[i].click();
  }
}
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children